# How do you taunt?

Tags: nier-automata

In NieR: Automata, one of the support plug-in chips is "Taunt Up" which raises your attack power, and your enemies' attack power, by a certain percentage. I've looked through the control schemes and couldn't find a way to taunt. Did I miss the part in the beginning of the game when they introduced this mechanic, or is there something special I have to do to taunt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taunting was not a mechanic that was explained in depth at any point, at least not until you start Route C/D and start controlling A2. Taunting as A2 is pretty straightforward, but apparently *all* characters can taunt.

According to the [wiki](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Taunt+Up), anyone can taunt by repeatedly flashing your flashlight in enemies' faces. The flashlight can be toggled on PS4 by pressing the L3 button and <kbd>2</kbd> on PC.

> All characters can taunt by toggling the flashlight repeatedly with the enemy in the light's path.

Additionally, A2 can taunt enemies by holding down the light attack button (this is in lieu of an additional attack that 2B and 9S have). When A2 taunts this way, it affects a larger area than toggling the flashlight.

Comment: [This](http://twinfinite.net/2017/03/nier-automata-taunt-chip-how-get-use/) guide gives a pretty good explanation as well

Comment: @Wondercricket ah, okay, so there *was* a short tutorial about it. I had no idea that toggling your flashlight would also taunt enemies though.

Comment: @Wondercricket ah ok, I haven't made it to the third playthrough yet. Also, I never used the flashlight much, so I may need to start doing that too.